Implement Dynamic Linking with Specific Url in react native
My url is
www.remo.com/whatsapp

I want only above url will open my app in mobile. As if there any another urls like
www.remo.com/abc
www.remo.com/aac

these will work as before. So basically i am getting a whatsapp message and in that i am getting a url like this
www.remo.com/whatsapp?data=ajicjajdiaj

so i want to open my if url is of this how can i do it in react native dynamic links.
